# Swift check non empty values

Tags: swift, dictionary

How to do the following?
First i have a dictionary, it is `[“a”: [“b”, “”], “b” : []]`
Then i want me when I call myDict.nonEmptyValues, then return `[“a”: [“b”]]`

how???
I searched lots of website but still not useful, please helpppppp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dict: Dictionary<String, [String]> = ["a": ["b", ""], "b" : []]

var newDict = dict.filter({!$0.value.isEmpty})
    

newDict.forEach({ (key, value) -> Void in
    newDict[key] = value.filter{!$0.isEmpty}
})

print(newDict)
```